# comma separated value in sql statement from a variable

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting comma separated value like this in a variable (let say variable name @listobj)

```
'abc' , 'xyz'
```

but when I am using below statement it is not giving me the correct result

```
SELECT * FROM someTable
Where column1 IN (@listobj)
```

but abc is present in the table.

Where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: This link discusses the problem in detail:


http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function  that split the string to

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
declare @idx int     
declare @slice varchar(8000)     

select @idx = 1     
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

while @idx!= 0     
begin     
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
    if @idx!=0     
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
    else     
        set @slice = @String     

    if(len(@slice)>0)
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
    if len(@String) = 0 break     
end 
return     
end

then make call to the function SELECT * FROM someTable
Where column1 IN (dbo.Split(@listobj))
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999631/split-string-by-comma-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/883d3/1)

```
select * from someTable
where ','+LTRIM(RTRIM(@listobj))+',' LIKE '%,'+LTRIM(RTRIM(column1))+',%'
```

Comment: this isn't working. When I doing hard coded value then it is working fine but not with a variable :(

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: I think it it because `column1` or `@listobj` has spaces in the end. For example it they aren't VARCHAR() but CHAR(). I've changed SQL to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A classic question and the answer is no, you cannot use a parameter in this way. There are several workarounds though

One of which is to parse the value inside the stored procedure and dynamically generate sql inside the procedure to be execute later. However, this is not a good practice.

Refer to this question

[How to pass a comma separated list to a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369/how-to-pass-a-comma-separated-list-to-a-stored-procedure)

and also some good discussion on it here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/1ccdd39e-8d58-45b2-9c21-5c4dbd857f95/